# 2 fragments in 1 frame

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 1 frame and 2 fragment use for backstack but i had a problem.
if i add fragment 2 to frame and add to Backstack. I can click on the same place on fragment2 but the effect is on fragment 1. how i can fix that?Thanks alots!

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container,false);
    Button b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"FR1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}
BackstackActivity

```
public class BackstackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnFrag;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_backstack);
    btnFrag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_replace_fragment);

    btnFrag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            addFragment(new Fragment2());
            Log.e("Replaced fragment", "2");
        }

    });
    replaceFragmentContent(new Fragment1());
}
protected void replaceFragmentContent(Fragment fragment) {

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fmgr = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fmgr.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);

        ft.commit();

    }

}
protected void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentManager fmgr = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fmgr.beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.container_body, fragment);

    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    ft.commit();

}
```

}

Comment: Add class details of your `fragment2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fragment2` layout xml file set your root layout as `clickable="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: @tuấnvũhữu Your welcome. Please accept my answer if it helps you :)